# valgrind and openmp, still reachable and possibly lost, is that bad?

Tags: c++, openmp, valgrind

c++ newbie here.

I've been improving my memory management skills over the last few days, and my program no longer leaks memory according to valgrind. In fact, I get no warnings from valgrind at all.

However, when I add openmp loops into my code, I start to get the following errors in valgrind (memcheck): (but no definitely lost blocks)

```
==6417== 304 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 4
==6417==    at 0x4C279FC: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==6417==    by 0x4011868: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:300)
==6417==    by 0x6649871: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:570)
==6417==    by 0x62263DF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==6417==    by 0x42A2BB: Blade::updatePanels() (blade.cpp:187)
==6417==    by 0x418677: VLMsolver::initialiseBlade() (vlmsolver.cpp:590)
==6417==    by 0x415A1B: VLMsolver::start(std::string) (vlmsolver.cpp:80)
==6417==    by 0x40B28C: main (charybdis.cpp:176)
```

and:

```
==6417== 1,568 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==6417==    at 0x4C28FAC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==6417==    by 0x6221578: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==6417==    by 0x6226044: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==6417==    by 0x622509B: GOMP_parallel_start (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==6417==    by 0x41AF58: VLMsolver::segmentCirculations() (vlmsolver.cpp:943)
==6417==    by 0x415E4B: VLMsolver::solveManager() (vlmsolver.cpp:177)
==6417==    by 0x415A4B: VLMsolver::start(std::string) (vlmsolver.cpp:91)
==6417==    by 0x40B28C: main (charybdis.cpp:176)
```

Is this a case of valgrind not understanding the openmp? Or is it something that might become sinister?

Note that when I run valgrind with helgrind, I get thousands of "possible data race during read" (and write) messages. However my program (a fluid dynamics solver) gives the same results for both the openmp and serial codes. I can provide the helgrind errors and relevant sections if you are interested in that for this problem.

Otherwise for now, here is the offending code for the second message: and line 943 is the pragma line.

```
for (int b = 0;b < sNumberOfBlades;++b) {
*VLMSOLVER.CPP LINE 943 is next*:
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) num_threads(2) firstprivate(b) 
    for (int i = 0;i<numX;++i) {
        for (int j = 0;j<numY;++j) {
            if (j == 0) {
                blades[b].line[i*numNodesY+j].circulation = blades[b].panel[i*numY+j].circulation;
            } else {
                blades[b].line[i*numNodesY+j].circulation =  blades[b].panel[i*numY+j].circulation - blades[b].panel[i*numY+j-1].circulation;
            }
            if (j==numY-1) {
                blades[b].line[i*numNodesY+j+1].circulation = -1 * blades[b].panel[i*numY+j].circulation;
            }

        }
    }
    if (sBladeSymmetry) {
        break;
    }
}

int k = numX*numNodesY;
for (int b = 0;b < sNumberOfBlades;++b) {
    for (int i = 0;i<numX;++i) {
        for (int j = 0;j<numY;++j) {
            if (i == 0) {
                blades[b].line[k+i*numY+j].circulation = - 1 * blades[b].panel[i*numY+j].circulation;
            } else {
                blades[b].line[k+i*numY+j].circulation = -1 * blades[b].panel[i*numY+j].circulation + blades[b].panel[(i-1)*numY+j].circulation;
            }
            if (i==numX-1) {
                blades[b].line[k+(i+1)*numY+j].circulation =  blades[b].panel[i*numY+j].circulation;
            }
        }
    }
    if (sBladeSymmetry) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Still reachable` is **not a memory leak.**

`Still reachable` means that a block of memory has not been freed but there are still valid pointers to the start of that block in registers or memory that has not been freed.

You need to have a look at **[the Valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports)**. The actual reason for `libgomp` causing the warning is explained **[here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36298)**.

Comment: so leaving memory still reachable is a feature of openmp, just as it might be for STL cases as in that link?

Comment: @CptLightning: I would believe so, but I have not really worked with OpenMP so I cannot say for sure if that is the case. You will need to see if OpenMP also uses the same fundamentals as by STL, which the link explains and talks about.

Comment: Any idea why valgrind reports `possibly lost` too? I can still reproduce it today.