# Compiling with OpenMP results in a memory leak

Tags: c, gcc, memory-leaks, openmp

According to valgrind, I can induce a memory leak when compiling a simple hello-world program with OpenMP. This doesn't make sense, because the hello-world program does not intentionally use any OpenMP functionality.

Suppose the program below is named `hi.c` and compiled according to

`$ gcc -o hi hi.c`

GCC version 4.8.3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  printf( "hi\n" );
  return 1;
}
```

We should expect a leak report from valgrind to verify the obvious: there are no leaks. My observations agree with this hypothesis:

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck ./hi
==13064== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13064== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13064== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13064== Command: ./hi
==13064== 
hi
==13064== 
==13064== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13064==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13064==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==13064== 
==13064== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13064== 
==13064== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13064== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

I would also expect to receive the same report after compiling with other flags. However, this is not the case. When I compile with the `-fopenmp` flag, I observe a memory leak

`$ gcc -fopenmp -o hi hi.c`

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck ./hi
==13084== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13084== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13084== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13084== Command: ./hi
==13084== 
hi
==13084== 
==13084== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13084==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==13084==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 32,824 bytes allocated
==13084== 
==13084== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13084==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13084==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13084==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13084==    still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==13084==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13084== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==13084== 
==13084== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13084== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Does anyone understand why compiling with OpenMP causes this memory leak? Although this particular program does not invoke OpenMP, I want to be sure that I am handling memory properly when I do eventually use it.

Comment: Which version of `gcc`? Cannot reproduce with 4.4.7.

Comment: I'm using GCC version 4.8.3. I edited the post to include the version number.

Comment: I have noticed the same with 4.9.1 though. However I would argue to call it as _memory leak_. Term "still reachable" means that pointer was not lost during execution, and there is one missing `free()` call. If I recall correctly C standard stands that such pointers are automatically freed at exit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [valgrind and openmp, still reachable and possibly lost, is that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973489/valgrind-and-openmp-still-reachable-and-possibly-lost-is-that-bad)

Comment: There is a know issue with `libgomp` (the GNU OpenMP run-time library) and Valgrind's `memcheck` and a simple Google search would have brought you to several explanations why. It would also be nice to make yourself familiar with the search functionality of Stack Overflow (located in the top right corner of the page) as you are not the first person to ask the same question here.

Comment: Thank you for the responses everybody. Hristo -- that particular post may seem similar to mine, but it's not immediately clear they are causally connected. After all, I am compiling a different language -- perhaps even a different compiler -- so there's nothing to suggest a solution to my problem will fix the other problem and vice versa. Even if the problems were the same, the answer provided on that post is insufficient to answer my particular question, which is why the memory issue is caused in the first place.

Comment: No matter what language you use, GCC implements OpenMP using `libgomp` and if you take a closer look at the other question, you see this: `by 0x62263DF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)`. It's not a leak and that's explained in the manual that the answer to the other question links to. The actual cause is complex and is explained [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36298).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That valgrind report does not depict a memory leak.  The heap memory remaining allocated at program exit is still reachable.

Very likely your compiler's openmp implementation injects a global variable into your program, and causes it to be dynamically allocated as part of program startup (i.e. before `main()`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me look at the compiler's output to verify your answer.

Comment: Edited to change "static" to "global".

Comment: Not the compiler but one of the constructors of the OpenMP runtime library `libgomp.so` injects a TLS key that remains there until the very moment the process terminates.

Comment: @HristoIliev: fair enough, but I account libgomp.so part of the gcc's OpenMP implementation.  It is separate from the compiler itself, of course, but you don't (normally) need to know about it or link it explicitly.  YMMV.