# Memory Leak - OpenMP

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, openmp, valgrind

valgrind told me, that I have following problem in my code:

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
==18114==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18114==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18114==      possibly lost: 1,776 bytes in 3 blocks
==18114==    still reachable: 2,320 bytes in 4 blocks
==18114==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

This problem occurs in:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numThreads)
```

in

```
parallelCalc= new Calculator[numOff];

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numThreads) 
    for(int i = 1; i<=numOff;i++)
    {
        std::stringstream sstm;
        sstm << filename <<"/" << i<<".off";
        std::string aktFilename = sstm.str();


        Polyhedron *poly = new Polyhedron(aktFilename.c_str());
        parallelCalc[i-1].init(poly,consistentTargets->points,numTarget);
        parallelCalc[i-1].hfield();


        delete poly;
    }
```

I tried to set parallelCalc shared in openmp,(I think this is the problem, isn't it?) but when I do this, I get the error `MainController::parallelCalc is not a variable in clause shared`.
Could anyone give me a hint, how to solve this memory problem?

Comment: Is there any reason you use a pointer here?  If not you should use a loop local automatic object instead.

Comment: Are u sure the problem is related to omp? Does the error vanish if you disable omp?

Comment: yes, the serial version don´t have memory problems. And it is the same code just without     #pragma omp     I think, that openmp produces private prarallelcalcs for each thread and this is the problem of the leak, isnt it?

Comment: It has to be a pointer, because I need the result of each porallelCalc. And I know the size of the array only in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha it is years ago that I asked this question. The answer is simple. Fist of all "still reachable" is not an memory leak as it says in the [valgrind docs](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost)

> "still reachable" means your program is probably ok -- it didn't free some memory it could have. This is quite common and often reasonable. Don't use --show-reachable=yes if you don't want to see these reports.

And the other part: `possibly lost: 1,776 bytes in 3 blocks`

As you could read in [bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36298) or also in [memleak in openmp](https://medium.com/@auraham/pseudo-memory-leaks-when-using-openmp-11a383cc4cf9) it isn’t a memory leak.

Or in words of [memleak in openmp](https://medium.com/@auraham/pseudo-memory-leaks-when-using-openmp-11a383cc4cf9):

> In short, it seems like a memory leak but it is not. It is just an issue related to OpenMP and Valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for us to reproduce your error because the code is not complete.

I see one potential loss of memory. You have a new Calculator call but no matching delete.

In addition, there could be other memory statically allocated by indirect means that there is no way to free.

One way to figure out what's going on is to use valgrind in a mode where it will show you the specific items it thinks were leaked. I usually use

valgrind --verbose --num-callers=30 --track-fds=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes

This will dump lots more information allowing you to track down where valgrind thinks the leak is coming from. Use the stack traces valgrind gives you to figure out if you can safely ignore the "leaks" because you can't do anything about it or if you need to fix code you are writing.

Comment: See the following for possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391389/compiling-with-openmp-results-in-a-memory-leak?rq=1

Comment: Im not sure, this is the same. When I put parallelCalc = new parallelCalc() and delete parallelCalc inside the  for loop I do not get any leaks, but I need the results of parallelCalc.

Comment: are you deleting parallelCalc using 'delete [] parallelCalc'? Did you try running valgrind with the command line options mentioned above to see what valgrind pointed at?

Comment: Sorry meybe my english isnt good enough, I try it again. The error happens in the line #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numThreads). And I think the reason for that, is that openmp produces parallelCalcs for each thread. I also wrote that the serial version dosnt run into memory leaks.